# Need to use Custom form in SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form

I have migrated an old SharePoint site to SharePoint Online.

I have a list with a very customized form, and I want to use the same form in the new site.

How can I import the viewform.aspx to the new site and use it?

p.s. I tried creating a powerapp, but the functionality is a little complicated.
Hence I want to use the old form, at least for view/edit.
It is imperative that I use the old form here.

Comment: Whether you mean the display form in the classic list?

Comment: yeah, when I select open/Edit Item, I need to go to a different page edititem.aspx?ID=<id>

Answer (score 0):

1.Click Edit list in the list tab.

2.In the left side navigation bar -> Lists and Library -> Choose the list.

3.Click New in the Forms section.

[image]